# How to check permissions in my controller

Tags: permissions, laravel-8, roles

I'm new to Laravel and I'm writing a user management System on my own.
At this time,

- I can CRUD permissions, roles and users,
- I can check the permissions by the AuthServiceProvider@boot method like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Gate::before( function (User $user , $permission) {
        // App administrator
        if($user->getPermissions()->contains('appAll'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Permission check
        return $user->getPermissions()->contains($permission);
    });
}
```

In my AdminUserController, I can check the permissions like that:

```
public function index()
{
    if( Gate::check('createUser') || Gate::check('readUser') || Gate::check('updateUser') || Gate::check('deleteUser')) {
        return view('userMgmt/users/index', [
            'users' => User::getUsersWithRolesWithTexts()
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect(route('home'))->withErrors('You do not have required permission');
    }
}
```

That is working well.

BUT
Is this the right way to wrap each controller method with:

```
if( Gate::check(...) ...) {
    //Do what the method is supposed to do
}
else
{
    return redirect(route('SOME.ROUTE'))->withErrors('SOME ERROR OCCURRED');
}
```

It would be nice if someone can give me some ideas.
Tank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a controller helper function named [authorize](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers) that you can call from any method in a controller that extends `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`. This method accepts the action name and the model, and it will throw an exception if the user is not authorized. So instead of the `if...else` statement, it will be one line:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $post);

    // The current user can update the blog post...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice approach. And if I want to check multiple permissions like "permission1 AND permission2"? And if I want to check multiple permission like "permission OR permission2"?

Comment: You better define all your conditions in the policy. that would be `app/Policies/PostPolicy.php` in our example